# Fill Pandas Dataframe using Databricks

Tags: python, dataframe, append, databricks

i have some code which i'm writing to solve a problem for our devops team, the first of which is to help them locate files on blob storage as they only have azure explorer.

i will create a dataset which lists all the files in a certain directory, this can be parameterised.
this will hopefully be a triggered pipline where the devops team can earmark what files they want to interact with a move/copy the file to a different location all of which will be tracked and audited, however, im stuck at the first hurdle.

below is some code which i'm trying to populate a dataframe, but i only end up with 1 row.. i've tried following a few posts on here but i seems to be missing something.

can anyone spot where i went wrong?

note: walk_dirz is a function which uses

```
dbutils.fs.ls(dir_path)
```

to loop through directorys looking for JSON and TXT only

here is the part where i'm stuck

```
import os
import datetime
import pathlib

#from datetime import datetime as dt
import time 
import pandas as pd

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
   

os_file_list = walk_dirz('dbfs:/mnt/landing/raw/NewData/Deltas')


df1 = pd.DataFrame()

#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
  
for i in os_file_list:
    print(i)
    pn = i 
    new_row = {'path':pn}
      
    df1  = df.append(new_row , ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Never use `append` in a loop (also, `append` is deprecated). Collect all items in a list, **then** convert to DataFrame.

Comment: i had no idea append was depreciated

Answer (score 0):

this looked like its worked

```
for i in os_file_list:

    df = pd.DataFrame(os_file_list,columns =['Path'])
```